# How to calculate average and range after input into list?

Tags: python, input

I need some help regarding calculating averages and ranges. I am using built-in functions such as sum(), len(), etc. and cannot seem to calculate the average or range. I am using it to write a small piece of code for fun but cannot seem to get it to work. any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

```
x = 1
number_list = []

while x == 1:
     input_number = input("PLease input an integer")
     if str.isdigit(input_number) == True:
         number_list.append(input_number)
     else:
         print("Please input a valid integer only.")
     continueornot = input("Would you like to continue adding data? PLease input 'Yes' to continue, and anything else to quit.")
     if continueornot == 'Yes':
        x = 1
     else:
           
            print("Here is the maximum number:", max(number_list))
            print("Here is the minimum number:", min(number_list))
            print("Here is the count:", len(number_list))
            print("Here is the average:" + sum(number_list) / len(number_list))
            print("Here is the range:", range(number_list))
            quit()
```

Comment: What is not working? What input did you provide and what (wrong) results did you get?

Comment: I use numbers as the input as I have code to filter out non-integer answers, and when it reaches the average calculation it reads "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' "

Comment: That's because you need to cast `input_number` to an int when you put it in your list.

Comment: When you take input, it is automatically a string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415978/why-does-input-always-return-a-string

You can enclose it in int() like this: `number = int(input('give number'))`

You should also be aware of your if/else chaining and the loop. I suggest you go through step by step and consider when it loops back.

Comment: Thank you! Ill go through the code again and use your advice.

Comment: Besides the syntax errors, the logic an be improved and simplified further here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```py
if str.isdigit(input_number) == True:
    number_list.append(input_number)
```

to

```py
if input_number.isdigit():
    number_list.append(int(input_number))
```

The error is because you're trying to do those operations on a list of strings.

You can also remove the check against `True` since that is implicitly checking the truthiness and since `input_number` is already a `str`, you can call the `isdigit()` method directly.

Comment: You don't have to do extra step here. since the input_number is a string already, you can just check - if `input_number.isdigit()`  that's it.  Then do next .

Comment: I'd also remove the ` == True` from the boolean comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are appending strings to the list rather than integers and then you are applying arithmetic operations on it. So first you should convert the input number to int type.
Secondly range function will not give you the range of a list rather then it returns a sequence.

```
x = 1
number_list = []

while x == 1:
    input_number = input("PLease input an integer")
    if str.isdigit(input_number) == True:
        input_number=int(input_number)
        number_list.append(input_number)
    else:
        print("Please input a valid integer only.")
    continueornot = input("Would you like to continue adding data? PLease input 'Yes' to continue, and anything else to quit.")
    if continueornot == 'Yes':
        x = 1
    else:

        print("Here is the maximum number:", max(number_list))
        print("Here is the minimum number:", min(number_list))
        print("Here is the count:", len(number_list))
        print("Here is the average:" , sum(number_list) / len(number_list))
        print("Here is the range:", max(number_list)-min(number_list))
```