# New and still learning phython

Tags: python

I was making a basic addition calculator and here is what that code looked like:

```
Number_1 = input("what number?")
Operator = "will be added"
print(Operator)
Number_2 = input("What is the next number?")
A = Number_1+Number_2
print(A)
```

The problem is if I put in 2 and 2 expecting to get 4, I get 22. I know what it is doing, joining the two numbers, but I don't really know how to fix this...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does input() always return a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415978/why-does-input-always-return-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string, and adding two strings concatenates them. You need to cast the string to an integer using `int`.

```
Number_1 = int(input("what number?"))
Operator = "will be added"
print(Operator)
Number_2 = int(input("What is the next number?"))
A = Number_1+Number_2
print(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

`input()` always returns a `str`ing; you're going to need numbers if you want to add them up as numbers.

Assuming you'll want to go with integers to begin with (i.e. no decimals for now), use `int()` to cast those strings to numbers:

```
A = int(Number_1) + int(Number_2)
```

You could do that while `input()`ing too, á la

```
Number_1 = int(input("what number?"))
```

which might be clearer, as then you know you're always working with integers when the name of the variable is `Number`...